# Merging partitions using 3rd party software

Tags: macos, hard-drive, osx-lion

This has probably been discussed before and i tried the solution using disk utility .My partitions are like this

```
OS 
A
B
C
```

Ideally i wanted to merge the space in c and os .but turns out that is not possible since they are not together .Next thing I try doing is delete A and then try to merge but it wouldnt let me do that(couldnt delete a) .So now I am not sure if there is a way to merge my OS drive with another empty partition .Can you guys suggest some good free 3rd party software to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Mac has a very useful utility accessible from Terminal.I personally find it much better that the GUI Diskutility. Start up Terminal in Utilities, and type "diskutil help" w/o the quotation marks. You will get a comprehensive list of items which you can do with your disk/volume. I have used it to create, delete, merge, resize volumes/partitions without losing data. Nevertheless you should always backup before venturing. And also check [this](http://pitumbo.com/merge-or-combine-two-partitions-mac-osx) out.

Hope this helps.